# Userform Listbox

Tags: vba, catia

I have a problem in Catia macros. So, I have my "user form" and "list box". By clicking the button "preview" in the list filled with specific numbers. After the first click, everything is okay but after the second and all the next clicks, I have an empty string. how can I fix it? In this case "Phi", Theta, and step are variables.

```
If sumTHK <> 0 Then

   ' calcRLcm = calcRL1
    numX0 = Format(calcRL1, "###0.00")
    numLi = Format(calcRL2, "###0.00")
    If UserForm1.ChBoxShow = True Then
     UserForm1.ListBox2.AddItem
     UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 0) = A
     UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 1) = k
     UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 2) = j
     UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 3) = GeoThick
     UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 4) = numX0
    ' UserForm1.ListBox2.List(m, 4) = numLi
     m = m + 1

     A = A + 1
     
     End If
Else
    calcRLcm = 0
End If
```

[image: Listbox Image]

Comment: Problem should not be in the code you are showing. Can you please share your events. Dont you have a SelectChange ?

Comment: hi, Disvoys there is full action in my code and shown my problem here.... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zGSW-evqMI1qP5WSWEBVjFuqOm6y_561/view?usp=drive_link